# Rename multiple directories

Tags: find, directory, rename

I want to find all directories with the last subdirectory named *doc*, for then rename them to *Doc*. How can be renamed?

I've the first part:

```
find -type d -name 'doc'
```

which returns directories paths like:

```
./foo/bar/doc
```

Comment: What about to use command rename? In flag *-exec*

Comment: If `rename` works for you by all means use it.  The trouble is there is no standard `rename(1)` command, so unless you tell everyone your version of `rename` we can't really help you with that approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find . -depth -type d -name doc -exec sh -c 'mv "${0}" "${0%/doc}/Doc"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

In zsh, you can use the [`zmv` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) to mass-rename files:

```
zmv '(**/)doc' '${1}Doc'
```

If you have non-directories called `doc`, make sure not to match them by adding a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

```
zmv -Q '(**/)doc(/)' '${1}Doc'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to capitalize the directory and you're using `bash` 4+ this should do:

```
find . -type d -name doc -print0 \
| while read -rd $'\0' file; do
    dname=$(dirname "$file")
    fname=$(basename "$file")
    mv "$file" "$dname"/"${fname^}"
  done
```

Note the use of `\0` to ensure the correct handling of unusual filenames.

#### Update

As *jw013* points out in the comments `${var^}` doesn't work as I expected. I've amended the answer to separate the path into directory and filename and apply the `^` operator only to `$fname`.

Btw, thanks *rush* for adding the missing pipe.

Comment: I don't think `${var^}` expansion does what you want it to.  `var=./foo/bar/doc; echo ${var^}` gives `./foo/bar/doc`.  The `^` expansion only affects the first character.

Comment: @jw013: You're right, I've amended the answer.

Comment: .
├── cos
│   └── doc
├── doc
└── tt
    **└── doc**
        └── kk

Comment: (Sorry for the above). Unfortunately your solution doesn't work for following directory structure: `mkdir -p dir1/doc/dir2`. In this case even though doc directory isn't the last subdirectory (Marc's requirement) it is renamed.

Comment: Well the OP didn't specify any other selection criteria besides `-name doc`, but if only leaf directories should be matched a check that `$dir` only contains `.` and `..` subdirectories could be done.