# How to rename file in multiple sub directory?

Tags: rename

Suppose I have 3 sub directories. All of them contain a file named `old_file_name`. Now with a single command I want to rename all of them to `new_file_name`.

I tried

```
sudo find . -name "old_file_name" -exec rename old_file_name new_file_name {} \;
```

But it is showing following error:

> Bareword "new_file_name" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).

Comment: What have you tried? There are *many* questions here that are almost identical, e.g. [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43902).

Comment: Why does it need to be a single command?

Comment: I tried
sudo find . -name "old_file_name" -exec rename old_file_name new_file_name {} \;

But it is showing following error:
Bareword "new_file_name" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).

Comment: @SudiptaSaha That's two commands, `find` and `rename` though. Is two commands ok?

Comment: @SudiptaSaha that error sounds like it's coming from perl. Perl has a File::Find module that you could use instead of shelling out for it. It even has a find2perl script that will convert (many) `find` calls to the corresponding File::Find code.

Answer (score 2):

The `perl` variants of `rename` take as argument first some `perl` code to transform file names and a list of files.

In your attempt you're calling it with `old_file_name` (which as `perl` code makes little sense; without `use strict`, it would just be treated the same as `"old_file_name"` and would have no effect) and `new_file_name` and the file found by `find` as file arguments to rename.

Here, you can just do:

```
find . -depth -name old_file_name -execdir mv old_file_name new_file_name \;
```

`-execdir` is not standard but fairly common.  Compared to `-exec`, it executes the command in the parent directory of each selected file instead of the current working directory of the `find` process.

Without `-execdir`, you could do:

```
find . -depth -name old_file_name -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    mv "$file" "${file%/*}/new_file_name"
  done' sh {} +
```

Comment: This will fails because there is no file named `old_file_name` in current directory.

Comment: @MUYBelgium, there will be as with `-execdir`, `find` sets the working directory of the process that executes the command to the parent directory of the matched file.

Comment: Effectivelly, but it is a good side note...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing fairly simple transformations of the filenames here, I don't really see the need to use `rename`.  Likewise, since you know that the files that you want to rename are located in the subdirectories of the current directory, and you seem to know their exact names, using `find` does not seem necessary either.

Assuming you have a number of subdirectories, each possibly containing some files and your `h` files.

To rename each of the `h` files into `he`, the simplest solution would be to loop over them and `mv` them to the new name.  In this case, since you are just adding the character `e` to the name, it becomes extra simple:

```sh
for name in ./*/h; do
    mv -i "$name" "$name"e
done
```

This loops over all the pathnames generated by the expansion of the `./*/h` pattern.  For each such name, the `mv -i` command is used to add a `e` at the end of it.  The `-i` option to `mv` will cause `mv` to ask for confirmation before replacing an existing name.

---

Update after updated question:

To rename all files called `old_file_name` in every subdirectory to `new_file_name`:

```sh
for name in ./*/old_file_name; do
    mv -i "$name" "${name##*/}/new_file_name"
done
```

or

```sh
for name in ./*/old_file_name; do
    mv -i "$name" "$( dirname "$name" )/new_file_name"
done
```

In both of these loops, the destination name has to be computed in such a way that it refers to the new filename in the same directory as where the old filename was located.

In the first loop we figure out the path to the directory using a standard variable substitution, `${name##*/}`, which will remove everything from `$name` up to and including the last `/`.  In the second loop, we use `dirname "$name"`, which does pretty much the same thing.  We then add `/new_file_name` to the end of the resulting string to form the full pathname for the new filename.

---

Finally, to use the Perl `rename` utility:

```
rename 's/old_file_name$/new_file_name/' */old_file_name
```

The issue that you had with your command was that it did not use a Perl expression as its first argument.  The `rename` utility takes a Perl expression that should transform the given pathnames, and applies it to each pathname in turn.  In the command above, we use a simple substitution expression that replaces the filename portion of the pathnames with the new filename.

Note that the substitution receives the full pathname and that we therefore need to make sure that to match the end of the sting (with `$`) to not accidentally rename any *directory* in the pathname that happen to be named `old_file_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of Stéphane Chazelas,

you may have to use quotes, definitely if any of the filename contains spaces, so `old_file_name` becomes `'old_file_name'`.  This seems usually the case if working on many files, use `'{}'` instead of `{}`.  I can't say at this point if quoting the accolades is appropriate when using the `-execdir` option.

Also, check the *find* man page, as it has a security warning that seems to apply in this case.